# How to Show the Magento Admin Config Errror Message Instead of Success Message?

Tags: magento

I have developed the new custom module with Admin panel Config Section. 
Also i have write the event observer for my custom config section save config button.
In this case i have validate the some data's to show the error message in my config section.

By Default when i click the custom config section it show default success message `"The configuration has been saved."` . But i need to show the Error Message instead of success message.

So can any one help me this situation.

Any Help Much Appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use try - catch construction to handle your errors correctly. On success - put in the session success message which you already have. On some core error you are able to use:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
try {
    .... 

} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    foreach(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()) as $message) {
        $session->addError($message);
    }
}
```

On PHP exception:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->addException($e,
        Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('An error occurred while saving this configuration:') . ' '
        . $e->getMessage());
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote an observer method on "admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}" event, you just need to throw Mage_Core_Exception with validation message in the method. See Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController::saveAction() method for more information.